# vim search a decimal but mismatch some other number

Tags: vim

When I use the vim to search a decimal(`/0.03`), like 0.03, in a text file, it will match not only the 0.03 but also the numbers such as 0403.

What should I use to replace the search equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dot is being interpreted as "a single arbitary character" as it is in regular expressions.

Escape the dot with the reverse slash, e.g. "0\.03" to match the literal dot symbol.

Comment: Thanks! It works, I don't know that the dot means a wildcard in vim before.

Comment: @Patrick, Not Just in Vim, dot matches a single arbitrary character in regular expressions, in general :)

Comment: @SibiCoder, got it, I'd better to look to some about the regular expressions :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for 0\.03 by escaping the decimal point.
Otherwise vim interprets the . as "any character" eg 4

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody else has mentioned it, you can also use the "nomagic" option. This signals to vim regex to treat meta characters, such as `.`, `^`, and `$` as literal characters.

```
/\V0.03
```

Will do what you're looking for. `\V` means no magic.

There's also "very magic" `\v` which treats regular characters like `()`, `<>`, and `|` as meta characters.